Confusing definition of a sub-region in Equations of Mathematical Physics
I am reading Vladimirov's Equations of Mathematical physics and I'm having trouble grokking a definition on page 3 chapter 1:
The bounded region $G'$ is called a subregion, strictly lying in the region $G$, if $G' \subset G$; in this connection it is written $G' \Subset G$. By virtue of the Heine–Borel lemma, there is a number $\epsilon > 0$ such that $G_\epsilon' \Subset G$.
where $G_\epsilon' = \bigcup_{x \in G'}OpenBall(x,\epsilon)$
If $G$ is the open-ball around the origin of radius $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $G'$ is an open-ball around $(0,0.5)$ of radius $0.5$ all the conditions for $G'$ to be a sub-region are met, however there is no $\epsilon > 0$ such that $G'_\epsilon \Subset G$. This leads me to believe then that "strictly" might mean that the closure of $G'$ is also contained in $G$, however, the text explicitly states $G' \subset G$. Is this a misprint?

What he wrote is nonsense. He should have said instead that the closure of $G'$ is a compact subset of $G$.
